# Android OnClickListener for Object based class

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am trying to implement ***OnClickListener*** for my class which is inherited from Object only. No View, or Activity.. But somehow, I am missing something and it doesnt work properly. Here is what I have.

```
class myActivity extends activity
{
    //variables and methods...

    private class testA implements OnClickListener
    {
        public testA()
        {
            setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

The structure is that. This works fine when I have only one instance of testA class. When I have multiple instances, when I click it any of the instances in the activity, the last created class receives the click event. All the instances receive the click event but the logic under onClick function applies only to the last one. I think I am missing a correct reference here.

***setOnClickListener*** in the *testA* constructor refers to *myActivity* class and ***this*** refers to testA class instance. I noticed that, when I call ***setOnClickListener*** for the next instance, the listener for *myActivity* class changes to the last created *testA* class. I just didn't get how to work around this. Maybe instead of ***setOnClickListener***, ***addOnClickListener*** might work well.

Anyone has idea about this? How can I make every created object to receive the click event properly?

I hope I could state what my problem is.. Thanks...

Comment: Attach the setOnClickListener() method in your myActivity class.

Comment: @Krylez setOnClickListener() in the testA constructor is actually for myActivity class. Because for every created instance I call setOnClickListener(), only the last instance receive the event from my Activity..

Answer (score 0):

My concept was wrong, only views receive OnClickEvent. So using implements to Object had no effect.

I changed the structure to

```
class myActivity extends activity
{
    //variables and methods...

private void initialize()
{
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            testA test = findTestA(event.getX(), event.getY());
                if (test != null)
                    test.receiveOnTouch(event);
    }
});
}    

private class testA 
{
    public testA()
    {
    }

    public void receiveOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        //do something with event
    }
}

}
```